# What is the stereochemistry resulting from hydroboration of 1-methylcyclopentene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, c-c-addition, organoboron-compounds

> What is the major product of the following reaction sequence?
>
> [image]

I'm supposed to work out the structures of both **2** and **3**, but I already know **2** to be 1-methylcyclopentene (as the most substituted alkene is formed during elimination).

For the hydroboration step, boron should add to the less substituted carbon (in an anti-Markovnikov fashion). However, I'm not sure which of the two choices **B** and **C** is correct. Why should one diastereomer be formed preferentially over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second step is a *syn* addition of the boron hydride. As depicted below, it will result in an *anti*-Markovnikov product with the boron on the less-substituted carbon. **Both hydrogen and boron are on the same side of the former double bond** and these two are the ones we refer to when we say *syn* addition.

The final step, the oxidation by hydrogen peroxide, is stereospecific with retention. So the newly-formed $\ce{C-O}$ bond is on the same side as the former $\ce{C-B}$ bond. Thus, an *anti* relationship is established between the methyl group and the hydroxy group.

Since 1-methylcyclopentene is planar, a racemic mixture of enantionmers is formed; neither *re* nor *si* side are favoured. The scheme below shows the attack from the *si* side of the $\mathrm{C2}$ atom.

[image]